# Use Regex to extract column data in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, json, regex

I have a column with JSON data. How can I use regex in SQL to extract the value to columns

Table `json_table`

```
Column 1: timestamp
Column 2: name
Column 3: json_column
{
   key1 : "value1"
   key2 : "value2"
}
```

I want to do the following

```
SELECT timestamp, 
name, 
(REGEX on json_column) as key1,
(REGEX on json_column) as key2,
FROM json_table
```

Comment: Wy not use a JSON function like [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) for that ?

Comment: Can you, please, add some sample input data, and required output data to your question ?  The answers will be more in the direction of YOUR data when you do so...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `json_column` is actually valid JSON i.e.

```json
{
   "key1" : "value1",
   "key2" : "value2"
}
```

You can simply use the inbuilt JSON functionality in MySQL 5.7 and above:

```sql
SELECT `timestamp`, 
      name, 
      json_column->>'$.key1' AS key1,
      json_column->>'$.key2' as key2
FROM `json_table`
```

Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/AYTUKlYF)

If you're not using one of these versions, you really need to upgrade as earlier versions have been out of support for a *long* time now.